# Gem::FilePermissionError при bundle install

Tags: ubuntu, ruby

Ввел команду:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Product \ title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal
```

На что выдало ошибку:

> Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

Запустил `bundle install`, и снова ошибка:

> An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
>   continue.
>
> Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.

Ок, запускаю команду `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'`. И снова ошибка:

> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>
> You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory.

Использую *Linux Ubuntu 14.04*.

Что происходит и как установить *sqlite3*?

Comment: Переименуйте вопрос, чтобы название отражало проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вы устанавливали Ruby и RubyGems через `apt`, они размещены "в системе", посему новые гемы без особых указаний можно устанавливать только через `sudo`, от рута.

Можно изменить местоположение устанавливаемых гемов, [задав переменную окружения `GEM_HOME`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911246/how-to-change-the-path-where-ruby-gems-are-installed-on-os-10-6-6-ruby-1-8-and-r) на какую-то папку внутри вашей домашней папки, куда доступ у вас однозначно есть (в т. н. userspace).

А можно установить [RVM](http://rvm.io/), который по умолчанию ставится в userspace (не "в систему") и в довесок позволит с лёгкостью установить более новые версии Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0) ruby'

вам надо установить пакет `ruby-sqlite3`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет добавить такой параметр?

```
bundle install --path ~/.gem
```

Answer (score 0):

Системый руби в Убунте по умолчанию ставит свои gem-ы в папки, недоступные простым пользователям. Рекомендую использовать [**rvm**](https://rvm.io/) для управления версиями ruby.

Установка rvm (лучше скопировать с [сайта](https://rvm.io/)):

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Установка нужного вам ruby (судя по вопросу, **1.9.1**):

```
rvm install 1.9.1
rvm use --default use 1.9.1
```

После этого `bundle` должен заработать. Только не забудьте перезапустить консоль.